# How to prove that for any vector $v \in V$, $v -Tv$ is either an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$, or the zero vector.

Tags: abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, such that $T^2$ is the identity operator.

Prove that for any vector $v \in V$, $v -Tv$ is either an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$, or the zero vector.

I'm not really sure how to start this. Is writing $T^2v = Iv , T^2v - Iv = 0 , v(T^2 - I) = 0$ a good way to start?

Comment: $T(v-Tv)=Tv-T^{2}v=Tv-v=(-1)(v-Tv)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm is it okay if I just apply the linear operator to $v-Tv$? And how do I prove for the zero vector?

Comment: What is the definition of an eigen vector?

Comment: Going from $T^2v-Iv=0$ to $v(T^2-I)=0$ is a very bad way to start, since $vT$ is a nonsense. But, yes, of course it is OK to apply $T$ to $v-Tv$. And, note that, by the definition of "eigenvector", the zero vector isn't one.

Comment: @geetha290krm an eigenvector is a vector which when multiplied with a matrix, gives you a scalar multiple of itself. actually after defining it, i realise how my question about the zero vector isn't useful.

Comment: Not correct! It is a **non-zero** vector with that property.  Zero vector is not an eigen vector for any matrix.

Comment: oh yes I missed that part, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X = v - Tv$

In Case $X = 0$ , we have nothing more to check.

In the other Case , we use the Definition of Eigenvector :
I will write out in very Detailed way , which can be shortened when OP gets more Practice :
$T X = \lambda X$
$T (v - Tv) = \lambda X$
$T v - T^2v = \lambda X$
$T v - Iv = \lambda X$
$T v - v = \lambda X$
$-[ -T v + v ] = \lambda X$
$-[ v - T v ] = \lambda X$
$-X = \lambda X$
Hence $\lambda = -1$ , that is , Eigenvalue is $-1$

[[ When we have $T X = \lambda X$ , where $X$ is Non-Zero , then Definition says that $\lambda$ is Eigenvalue & $X$ is Eigenvector , That is what the given Question means ]]

ADDENDUM :

OP was using this :
$T^2v = Iv\ ,\ T^2v - Iv = 0\ ,\ \color{red}{v(T^2 - I)} = 0$
The term with highlight is wrong on 2 ways :
(1) We can not factorize like Integers or real numbers , with Commutative Property.
(2) We can not even calculate $\color{blue}{v(T^2 - I)}$
It should actually be $\color{green}{(T^2 - I)v}$